# ng2 component in angularjs (1.5) application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to use angular2 component in my angularjs (v1.5) application.
with pure js (ES6) I succeeded to run an ng2 component in my application with `downgradeNg2Component` function of `UpgradeAdapter` class.

I'm bootstrap my application with the following code:

```
var upgradeAdapter = new ng.upgrade.UpgradeAdapter();
    upgradeAdapter.bootstrap(document.getElementById("my-container"), ["MyModule"]);
```

and it works fine.

The problem is when Im trying to use TypeScript.
I created a component that looks like: (**pmComponent.ts**)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'appi',
    template: `
    <div class="app">
      HELLO 
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

my HTML looks like:

```
<script>
        System.import('pmComponent.js').then(module => {
            angular.module('MyModule').directive(
                    'appi',
                    window.upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Component(module.AppComponent));
        }).catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
<appi></appi>
```

and I'm getting the error message:
**EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on AppComponent**

Can someone please help me with that issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any repo to reproduce it?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't. I am working with TFS and the project is too big to export it to external resource.